# Multiple Ajax requests unexpected ajaxstart behavior

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm sending out multiple Ajax requests in a loop like this

```
for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "info.php",
       data: {somedata:lines[i]},
       success :function(data){}
   })
}
```

and using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        $("#wait").css("display","block");
    });
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        $("#wait").css("display","none");
    });
});
```

To show an Ajaxloader. But the problem is, as soon as the first request gets through, the loader doesn't appear for the next request, am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `counter` variable, this way the loading animation will be shown until the last ajax request finished, ex:

```
var counter = 0;

$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    counter++;
    if(counter)
        $("#wait").css("display","block");
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    counter--;
    if(!counter)
        $("#wait").css("display","none");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs

> Description: Register a handler to be called when the first Ajax request begins. This is an Ajax Event.

So it was only called for the first request and the

> $(document).ajaxComplete

part in my code waited for the first request to complete, I should've used

> $(document).ajaxStop

instead. Bad w3schools.com ajaxloader tutorial!